# What is the job of jsp:setProperty tag?

Tags: java, jsp

Jsp page contains a code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="loginBean" class="bean.LoginBean">
    <jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

where LoginBean includes `private String userName, password;`

It's not clear what is the `jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*"` do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*" />`, if `loginBean` is not available a new one will be created and all properties of the new bean will be set the value of all matching named parameters

Answer (score 0):

> `<jsp:setProperty>` tag is used to set the value(s) of property(ies) in JavaBean component, to set the value(s) this tag uses the setter method defined in the Bean. This tag can't be used without `<jsp:useBean>` tag so, it is necessary to use the "useBean" tag to declare the Bean. You would have to careful while assigning the value of name attribute of `<jsp:setProperty>` tag, value of name must be the same as the value of id attribute of `<jsp:useBean>` tag.

For asterisk (*) used here `<jsp:setProperty name="loginBean" property="*" />` is used as the property attribute value of the action. This means that all bean properties with names that match request parameters sent to the page are set automatically